# Combining several if statements in Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I need to create a logical statement that applies the right variables according to both the environment type and region code of the resource being deployed.

I need to be able to check `DEV`, `QA` and `PRD`, however the `PRD` environment's region codes also need to be checked. `DEV` and `QA` don't.

So I need to be able to do something like `if dev then var1; else if qa then var2; else if prd then if use then var3 else var4`

The problem is I don't really want to build this using a bunch of `if()` and `and()` template functions, as this is going to get absurdly messy very quickly and is going to be a readability and maintainability nightmare.

I'm aware that Azure ARM tempates don't support switch statements, but is there anything I can do to get the result I need short of combining ~10 if statements?

Answer (score 0):

do this outside of arm template and pass the result to it or use an object as a switch?

```
"myObject": {
    "dev": "xxx",
    "qa": "yyy",
    "prod": {
        xx: xxx,
        yy: yyy,
        zz: zzz
    }
}
```

and you can just do:

```
var1: variables('myObject')[parameters('selector')]
```

the only thing you'd need to implement then - is a check, if its prod, you need to go deeper :)

Comment: Am I able to create non-arm json objects within an arm template as I would like any other variable?

Comment: sorry, can you rephrase? i dont understand your question. basically, you can define a variable of type object and can give it any structure (if that is the question). but iths object is a valid json object (apart from me not wanting to type `"` in the last part of the object)